# MOQ Returns returning Null

Tags: c#, tdd, moq

i'm currently working on my testproject to test all of my domain entities in the same way. Therefore, I made a base class, which will be inherited by all of my test classes, to ensure that all of them share the same behavior.

All of my methods work fine, except for the GetByPrimaryKey, which returns null when it should return an instance of my type.

Implementation of the base class:

```
[TestClass]
public abstract class RepositoryTestBase<E, C>
    where E : EntityBase
    where C : IDBContext
{
    protected E MockedEntity;

    protected IRepository<E, C> Repository { get { return _mockedRepository.Object; } }

    private Mock<IRepository<E, C>> _mockedRepository;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Init()
    {
        MockedEntity = System.Activator.CreateInstance<E>();

        _mockedRepository = new Mock<IRepository<E, C>>();

        _mockedRepository.Setup(f => f.Add(MockedEntity)).Callback(() => { MockedEntity.Id = 1; });

        _mockedRepository.Setup(f => f.GetByPrimaryKey(MockedEntity.Id)).Returns(MockedEntity);

        _mockedRepository.Setup(f => f.Update(MockedEntity)).Callback(() => { MockedEntity.AlteradoEm = DateTime.Now; });

        _mockedRepository.Setup(f => f.Remove(MockedEntity)).Callback(() => { MockedEntity.Deleted = true; });
    }
}
```

How can I make the Returns() method return an object instead of returning null? And why is it returning null? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem. The above code still leaves things too broad to be able to properly help. Show how a derived test would be constructed and exercised.

Comment: Is it possible (would be able to tell if executing code was posted, as @Nkosi stated) that you are calling the mocked "Add" before calling the mocked "GetByPrimaryKey" --> when you create the new entity, the Id = 0, so your mock setup is then only going to return an entity when the input is 0, and if you've set it to 1, since it's using the same instance, it's not matching your setup...

Answer (score 3):

Since you only have a single MockedObject, you don't really care about the input parameter into the mock repository setup.

As such, you could do something like:

```
_mockedRepository.Setup(f => f.GetByPrimaryId(It.IsAny<int>()).Returns(MockedEntity);
```

where  is the type of your entities' key (or whatever "GetByPrimaryId" expects)

Answer (score 0):

> why is it returning null?

The `Id` has the potential to change. Using the constant `MockedEntity.Id` which would default to `0` at the time of setup would cause the problem you are experiencing because if you were to call the mocked method after having already added it to the repository the `Id` would not match and the mocked behavior would not be exercised.

> How can I make the Returns() method return an object instead of returning null?

Instead make the `Returns()` statement flexible by using `It.IsAny<int>()` in the setup and comparing the provided `Id` to the current `Id` of the entity, only returning the entity if the Ids matches.

```
_mockedRepository
    .Setup(_ => _.GetByPrimaryKey(It.IsAny<int>()))
    .Returns((int id) => id == MockedEntity.Id ? MockedEntity : default(E));
```